# At least one object must implement IComparable error in linq query

Tags: c#, linq

```
var pairs = new [] { new { id = 1, name = "ram", dept = "IT", sal = "3000" }, new { id = 2, name = "ramesh", dept = "IT", sal = "5000" }, new { id = 3, name = "rahesh", dept = "NONIT", sal = "2000" },
                             new { id = 5, name = "rash", dept = "NONIT", sal = "7000" } };
        var query = from stud in pairs
                    where (stud.name.StartsWith("r") && stud.id % 2 != 0)
                    //orderby stud.sal descending
                    group stud by stud.dept into grps
                    select new { Values = grps, Key = grps.Key, maxsal=grps.Max() };
                    ////select new { id = stud.id };

        foreach (dynamic result in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result.Key);
            Console.WriteLine(result.maxsal);
            foreach (dynamic result2 in result.Values)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result2.id + "," + result2.sal);
            }


        }
        Console.Read();
```

I am getting the error "At least one object must implement IComparable.", can someone explain me why iam I getting this error ?

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `grps.Max()` to get maximnum item in group. Your anonymous objects are not comparable. How Linq will know which one is maximum from them? Should it use `id` property for comparison, or `name`?

I believe you want to select max salary:

```
maxsal = grps.Max(s => Int32.Parse(s.sal))
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction , but I didn't get the error once I replaces with the lamda expression you gave , so where Is the point of tyepe Icomparable here then  ? I would like to know the story behind the Icomparable for linq sorting compared to sql sorting , can you help me understanding the same